# Stellar smart contract

Tags: transactions, stellar-core

Where does the stellar smart contracts stored. Its storing in blokchain (similar like ethereum) or its runs separately and storing only the signed transactions?. As i know stellar stores only the transactions in ledger so where the contracts stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/walkthroughs/stellar-smart-contracts.html

> A Stellar Smart Contract (SSC) is expressed as compositions of transactions that are connected and executed using various constraints

SSCs are not stored as executable contracts. They are formed as the logical outcome of constraints placed around transactions.

The constraints available include:

> - Multisignature - What keys are needed to authorize a certain operation? What parties need to agree on a circumstance in order to execute the steps?
> - Batching/Atomicity - What operations must all occur together or fail? What must happen in order to force this to fail or pass?
> - Sequence - In what order should a series of transactions be processed? What are the limitations and dependencies?
> - Time Bounds - When can a transaction be processed?

Examples of how to construct SSCs are given in the [docs](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/walkthroughs/stellar-smart-contracts.html) and [this repo](https://github.com/zulucrypto/stellar-smart-contracts).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So the contract transactions are stored in any place inside blockchain?. because i am having a doubt if the contract not stored inside blockchain then there are possibilities to modify in future. So how stellar controlling the future contract modifications?.

Comment: Yes, the individual transactions are recorded in the ledgers once submitted. But, more to the point, signed transactions cannot be modified by other parties, whether they have been submitted or not. You can take this conversation to the slack channel for the finer details.

Comment: Sure thanks for the details. As i understand in stellar we need to must use transactions in order to create a contract. So it will not efficient and flexible enough as ethereum

Comment: I argue that it's 1: more efficient; 2: less flexible; 3: less flexible == more secure

Comment: i agree the term of security but cant write logic as we want because we have transaction restriction. it will be supper efficient for contracts that dealing with money but for only transfer assets or record data without any money involvement stellar will be not the first choice.

Comment: As i got the understanding stellar contract will be good for the crypto projects and money transactions, because when we create contract it store only transaction hash not any other logic. if i am right