# Is it possible to implement custom transaction types in Stellar?

Tags: stellar-core

I see that it is possible to add custom data, but it seems like there is no validation of its correctness on the blockchain side. So the question - is it possible to implement custom transaction types with custom state and validation logic (not necessarily linked to cryptocurrency) without forking Stellar core code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's impossible without changing the protocol. Basic validation and smart contracts logic can be implemented on top of transaction preconditions, read more [here](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/701/stellar-smart-contract). Use cases are somewhat limited, but [CAP-21 proposal](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/core/cap-0021.md) (hopefully we'll see it implemented by the end of the year) introduces more advanced preconditions for Stellar smart contracts.